# Content Slot will not show multiple content assets in Demandware

Tags: salesforce, demandware

I have read that you can add multiple content assets in a content slot. I created by content slot and the content assets, and I added each of them on their own line in the content slot. However, only the first one shows. Both are working because when I switch the order, the one on top always shows but not the second. I have read that it is possible to show multiple content assets bu adding them, and it even says you can add up to 20 content assets. Does anyone know how I can get my multiple content assets to show in a content slot?
Also this is my first post about Demandware, so not sure what other information is required to help answer this question but let me know and I will add it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign the right rendering template:

In your case *contentAssetBody.isml*

It should look like this:

```
<isif condition="${slotcontent != null}">
    <isloop items="${slotcontent.content}" var="contentAsset">
        <isprint value="${contentAsset.custom.body}" encoding="off"/>
    </isloop>
</isif>
```